# How do I fix the split screen?

Tags: user-interface, cobol

So I'm just wondering why my screen looks like this and how do I fix it. The screen splits down the middle where the color changes from orange to green so it looks for only the first part of that file when I run the code. I don't know why it's doing that or how to fix it.

[image: code split]

Comment: What editor/IDE is this?

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: If you are using a Micro Focus based product, then check either you Visual Studio project or eclipse project for the source format settings, it looks like it is set to "fixed" and you perhaps are requiring "variable" or "free"

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers allow for a free format but most that I've used (IBM) require fixed.  They have Area A and Area B which ends at column 72.  If you need to use long literals you'll have to use continuation.  The hyphen must appear in col 7 or you'll get a compiler error.  This is straight out of the GNUCobol manual but it's the same for IBM.

```
    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID.  LONGLIT.
    DATA DIVISION.

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  LONG-LITERAL-VALUE-DEMO     PIC X(60) VALUE "This is a long l
   -                                                "ong literal that
   -                                                " must be continu
   -                                                "ed.".

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

      DISPLAY LONG-LITERAL-VALUE-DEMO 
      STOP RUN
      .
```